# Error en POST con sweetAlert + php

Tags: php, sweetalert2

Tengo un error a la hora de pasar los datos de un formulario con sweetalert, los campos los rescato correctamente, al mandarlos obtengo el error:

> ```
> la data es: <br />
> <b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "nombre" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\panel\assets\insert.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
> <br />
> <b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "producto" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\panel\assets\insert.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
> <br />
> <b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "cantidad" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\panel\assets\insert.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
> <br />
> <b>Warning</b>:  Undefined array key "fecha" in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\panel\assets\insert.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
> INSERT INTO productos (nombre, producto, cantidad, fecha, total) VALUES ('', '', '', '', '0'){"success":true}
> ```

Mi codigo en el archivo php:

```
if (formValues) {
                        const [nombre, producto, cantidad, fecha] = formValues;
                        console.log(nombre, producto,cantidad,fecha)
                        fetch('assets/insert.php', {
                                method: 'POST',
                                headers: {
                                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                                },
                                body: JSON.stringify({
                                    nombre: nombre,
                                    producto: producto,
                                    cantidad: cantidad,
                                    fecha: fecha
                                })
                            })
                            .then(response => response.json())
                            .then(data => {
                                console.log("la data es: "+ data); // Muestra la respuesta completa en la consola
                                if (data.success) {
                                    Swal.fire('Éxito', 'Los datos se han insertado correctamente.', 'success');
                                } else {
                                    Swal.fire('Error', 'Ha ocurrido un error durante la inserción.', 'error');
                                }
                            })
                            .catch(error => {
                                console.error('Error en la solicitud:', error);
                            });
                    }
```

mi codigo para insertar es:

```
<?php
$enlace = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "losmantosspa");


    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $producto = $_POST["producto"];
    $cantidad = $_POST["cantidad"];
    $fecha = $_POST["fecha"];    
    $total = $cantidad * 2000;

    // Realiza la consulta SQL para insertar los datos
    $query = "INSERT INTO productos (nombre, producto, cantidad, fecha, total) VALUES ('$nombre', '$producto', '$cantidad', '$fecha', '$total')";
    $result = mysqli_query($enlace, $query); 
    echo $query;

    if ($result) {
        $response = ["success" => true];
    } else {
        $error = mysqli_error($enlace); // Obtén el mensaje de error de MySQL
        $response = ["success" => false, "error" => $error];
    }
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($response);
    

mysqli_close($enlace);
?>
```

Agradecería mucho su ayuda. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema, asumiendo que los valores tienen datos, es el uso **innecesario** de `JSON.stringify`, el cual lo que hace es crear una cadena, no un objeto JSON, que es lo que sería necesario enviar, dado que tienes un `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`.

Bastaría con ponerlo así:

```
                            body: {
                                nombre: nombre,
                                producto: producto,
                                cantidad: cantidad,
                                fecha: fecha
                            }
```

En Javascript, creas un objeto simplemente con usar `{}` y poner dentro la propiedad (a la izquierda)  y el valor (a la derecha) y separando por coma cada propiedad : valor.

Y aquí te voy a dejar una prueba, para que veas la diferencia. En tu actual código muestra `undefined`, porque no estás creando un objeto JSON realmente.

```js
let nombre = 'Pedro';
let producto = 'Un Producto';
let cantidad = 1;
let fecha = 20231030;

let fakeJson = JSON.stringify({
  nombre: nombre,
  producto: producto,
  cantidad: cantidad,
  fecha: fecha
});
console.log(fakeJson.nombre);

let trueJson = {
  nombre: nombre,
  producto: producto,
  cantidad: cantidad,
  fecha: fecha
};
console.log(trueJson.nombre);
```

Dicho eso, hay problemas también en tu código PHP.

En primer lugar, no deberías pasar a usar los valores ingenuamente, sin verificar si están vacíos o no fueron enviados. Esto va a romper el flujo, sobre todo cuando la petición espera en el cliente un json como respuesta. Cualquier cosa que salga por pantalla en un código no controlado va a romper el flujo.

Así, para evitar casos de *`Undefined index`*  puedes controlar usando fusión de null.

Debes quitar también el **`echo $query;`**, por lo mismo, porque esa salida va a romper el flujo.

Y debes cerrar todo antes, no después, porque este tipo de peticiones deben terminar con un `exit()`. Si no lo haces, en algunos casos el servidor agrega un salto de línea que también rompería el flujo.

Y, conviene agregar también el tipo de codificación de la respuesta, podrías tener problemas sino cuando haya palabras acentuadas.

Aplicando todo lo dicho, el código quedaría así:

```
<?php
    $enlace = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "losmantosspa");
    
    /*
       Usaremos fusión de null, 
       asumiendo que estás en PHP 7+
       de lo contrario, usa un operador ternario con empty()
    */
    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"] ?? null;
    $producto = $_POST["producto"] ?? null;
    $cantidad = $_POST["cantidad"] ?? null;
    $fecha = $_POST["fecha"] ?? null;  
    
    if ($nombre && $producto && $cantidad && $fecha) 
    {
        $total = $cantidad * 2000;
        $query = "INSERT INTO productos (nombre, producto, cantidad, fecha, total) VALUES ('$nombre', '$producto', '$cantidad', '$fecha', '$total')";
        $result = mysqli_query($enlace, $query); 

        if ($result) 
        {
            $response = ["success" => true];
        } 
        else 
        {
            $error = mysqli_error($enlace); // Obtén el mensaje de error de MySQL
            $response = ["success" => false, "error" => $error];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $response = ["success" => false, "error" => "Datos incompletos"];
        
    }
        mysqli_close($enlace);
        header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
        echo json_encode($response);
        exit();
?>
```

#### De obligada lectura

1. [Lo que hace realmente `JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)
2. [Trabajar con objetos en Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_objects)