# Al mandar los datos a traves de POST con ajax, mi codigo PHP no los recibe

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery

Pues eso, utilizo el siguiente código de JavaScript con jQuery para enviar los datos por Ajax con el método post a mi archivo PHP:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("Documento listo");

    $("#btnaceptar").click(function() {
      let email = $("#email").val();
      let password = $("#contraseña").val();
      
      if (email === "" || password === "") {
        if (email === "") {
          $("#mensaje1").html("Campo vacío");
        } else {
          $("#mensaje1").html("");
        }
  
        if (password === "") {
          $("#mensaje2").html("Campo vacío");
        } else {
          $("#mensaje2").html("");
        }
      } else {
        if(!email.includes("@") || password.length >= 8 && /\d/.test(password)){

        if (email.includes("@")) {
          $("#mensaje1").html("");
        } else {
          $("#mensaje1").html("No contiene un '@' ");
        }
        if (password.length >= 8 && /\d/.test(password)) {
          $("#mensaje2").html("");
           
        } else {
          $("#mensaje2").html("Se requieren 8 caracteres y un numero al menos");
        }
        
      } else {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '../PHP/login.php',
          data: {
              email:email,
              password:password
          },
          success: function(response) {
              console.log("Éxito");
              console.log(response);
              window.location.href = "../HTML/Homepage.html";
          },
          error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              alert("Error, " + error + xhr + status);
          }
      });      
      }
      }
    });
  });
```

Y luego lo tendría que recibir mi PHP; pero al entrar en el condicional del "if" este no recibe los datos desde el Ajax, en consola no tira ningún mensaje debido a que no entra en el mismo digo que no manda correctamente los mensajes desde el Ajax debido a que si cambio el condicional por un "empty" este ingresa y muestra los "echo" de mensajes de validación de datos:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';


$errorMSG = array();

if (
    isset($_POST['email']) &&
    isset($_POST['password'])
) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $Contrasena = $_POST['password'];

    // Consulta para verificar las credenciales
    $select_user_stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE `E-mail` = :email");
    $select_user_stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
    $select_user_stmt->execute();

    // Agrega mensajes de depuración
    echo "email: $email<br>";
    echo "Contraseña: $Contrasena<br>";

    // Verificar si se encontró un usuario con el correo electrónico dado
    if ($select_user_stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        $user = $select_user_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // Agrega mensajes de depuración
        echo "RowCount: " . $select_user_stmt->rowCount() . "<br>";

        // Verificar la contraseña
        if (password_verify($Contrasena, $user['Contraseña'])) {
            // Agrega mensaje de depuración
            $hashed_password = password_hash($user['Contraseña'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            echo "Contraseña almacenada: $hashed_password<br>";

            // La contraseña es correcta, iniciar sesión
            session_start();

            // Guardar información del usuario en la sesión (puedes personalizar esto según tus necesidades)
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['ID_Usuario'];
            $_SESSION['user_email'] = $user['E-mail'];
            $_SESSION['user_nombre'] = $user['Primer_Nombre'];

            // Redirigir a la página de inicio después del inicio de sesión exitoso
            header("Location: ../HTML/Homepage.html");
            exit;
        } else {
            // Contraseña incorrecta
            $errorMSG[] = "Contraseña incorrecta. Intenta de nuevo.";
        }
    } else {
        // Usuario no encontrado
        $errorMSG[] = "No se encontró un usuario con ese correo electrónico.";
    }
}

// Imprimir errores (si los hay)
if (!empty($errorMSG)) {
    foreach ($errorMSG as $error) {
        echo $error . "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Por si se lo requiere este es mi código HTML del login:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../src/TuLogo.png" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Sisviansa-Login</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/Login.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="../Boostrap/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../JS/login.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="bg-secondary d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center vh-100">


    <section class="bg-white p-5 rounded-5 text-secondary shadow principal">

      <section class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <a href="../HTML/Homepage.html"> 
          <img src="../src/TuLogo.png" height="200" width="200" alt="Logo"/>
        </a>
      </section>
      <section class="text-center fs-1 fw-bold">Login</section>

      <p class="Aviso">Todos los elementos con (*) son requeridos </p>

      <section class="input-group mt-4">
        <section class="input-group-text bg-warning">
          <img src="../src/user.png" class="d-block" alt="Usuario" />
        </section>
        <input class="form-control bg-light" type="email" placeholder="Email (*)" id="email" />
      </section>

      <p class="Error" id="mensaje1"></p>

      <section class="input-group mt-1">
        <section class="input-group-text bg-warning">
          <img src="../src/Lock.png" class="d-block" alt="Contraseña">
        </section>
        <input class="form-control bg-light" type="password" placeholder="Contraseña (*)" id="contraseña" />

      </section>

      <p class="Error" id="mensaje2"></p>

      <section class="d-flex justify-content-around mt-">
        <section class="pt-1">
          <a href="../HTML/Tutorial.html#Ayuda"
            class="text-decoration-none text-warning fw-semibold fst-italic">Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a>
        </section>
      </section>

      <button class="btn btn-warning text-black w-100 mt-4 fw-semibold shadow-sm " id="btnaceptar">
        Iniciar Sesion
      </button>


      <section class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-1">
        <section>No tienes una cuenta?
          <br>
          <a href="../HTML/RegisterUsuario.html" class="text-decoration-none text-warning fw-semibold">Registrarse como
            usuario</a>
          <br>
          <a href="../HTML/RegisterEmpresa.html" class="text-decoration-none text-warning fw-semibold">Registrarse como
            empresa</a>

        </section>
      </section>



    </section>


  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Pero ¿estás mandando la petición Ajax al mismo archivo que contiene el botón `btnaceptar`? El planteamiento de la pregunta no es claro. ¿Cómo se llama el archivo donde tienes los `isset`?

Comment: Saludos. El `data` del **Ajax** usa `data: JSON.stringify({email:email,password:password})` y agrega `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`. Espero sea lo que le está faltando.

Comment: @RobertoLeOr si usa `JSON.stringify` no estaría enviando un objeto JSON como tal, que es lo que se requiere. Los objetos se construyen justamente como OP los está construyendo: `data: { email:email, password:password}` Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/606900/29967) y el fragmento de código allí, donde se demuestra que `JSON.stringify` no crea un JSON como tal, sino una cadena que luego habría que reconvertir de nuevo en el servidor innecesariamente. Y, en el caso de Ajax, tampoco hay que poner el Content-type.

Comment: Saludos. @A.Cedano cuando inicie usar Ajax (de jQuery), me ocurria eso con el  `JSON.stringify` ya no se presento más; sin embargo, no uso (del ejemplo que pones) el `header:{ contenType:....}` lo uso (al mismo nivel del `data`) `data:..., contentType:...`

Comment: @RobertoLeOr quizá empezaste en una versión antigua de Ajax basado en jQuery. En el parámetro `data`, jQuery pide un [PlainObject](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject), el cual se puede definir simplemente como `{unaPropiedad: unValor, otraPropiedad: otroValor}` El `contenType` se lo puedes especificar si quieres, si no lo haces, el objeto será convertido a una cadena válida para el modo URL encoded: `unaPropiedad=unValor&otraPropiedad=otroValor`. Yo uso mis peticiones Ajax pasando los valores como objetos, sin `stringify` y funciona perfectamente.

Comment: El ejemplo de la respuesta que refiero en el enlace está basado en la API Fetch de Javascript, que es diferente a Ajax. Mi idea era que vieras que `stringify` no crea un objeto JSON válido en realidad, sin una cadena. Si tú quisieras hacerlo JSON de nuevo tendrías que usar `parse`, o sea reconvertir algo que convertiste previamente sin ninguna necesidad.